# Solve sin(θ) = x in the range a ≤ θ ≤ b

Tags: code-golf, math, number, trigonometry

### Challenge

Given a number, `x` where `-1 ≤ x ≤ 1`, and the integers `a` and `b`, where `b > a`, solve the equation `sin(θ) = x` for `θ`, giving *all* solutions in the range `a° ≤ θ ≤ b°`.

### Rules

`x` will have a maximum of three decimal places of precision. The output, `θ`, must also be to three decimal places, no more, no less.

Your output may be as a list or separated output.

You may use built-in​ trig functions.

You may not use radians for `a` and `b`.

You will never be given invalid input.

Output may be in any order.

### Examples

```
x, a, b => outputs
0.500, 0, 360 => 30.000, 150.000
-0.200, 56, 243 => 191.537
0.000, -1080, 1080 => 0.000, 180.000, 360.000, 540.000, 720.000, 900.000, 1080.000, -1080.000 -900.000, -720.000, -540.000, -360.000, -180.000
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Maths homework this time?

Comment: @Okx Of course xD

Comment: Grrr, angular degrees are evil.

Comment: 1. Can we go beyond 3 decimal places? 2. Do the outputs have to be in ascending order?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino 1. No, you must stick to 3 decimal places. 2. Outputs can be in any order

Comment: One can use arcsin()?

Comment: Can we return `1.0` instead of `1.000`?

Comment: @mbomb007 I've fixed the examples

Comment: @Uriel Not particularly

Comment: I think the 3 points precision here is ruining the challange, because it becomes a brute force instead of angles translation

Comment: @Uriel Huh, that's a shame. When you don't specify a challenge enough, people complain, when you specify the challenge, the challenge is a bit rubbish :P

Comment: For me less is specified better it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## APL, <s>51</s> <s>46</s> <s>40</s> 39 bytes

<sub>[*3 bytes saved thanks to @KritixiLithos*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37696773#37696773)</sub>

<sub>[*<s>6</s> 7 bytes saved thanks to @Adám*](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37698973#37698973)</sub>

```
{3⍕⍵/⍨1E¯6>|⎕-1○○⍵÷180}⊢+1E3÷⍨(⍳1001×-)
```

Called as a dyad with `a` as left argument and `b` as right argument, prompts for `x`.

Requires `⎕IO←0`.

**How?**

```
                         ⊢+1E3÷⍨(⍳1001×-)  ⍝ build the range a to b with step of 0.001
                                  1001×-   ⍝ 1001 * (b - a)
                                 ⍳         ⍝ range
                           1E3÷⍨           ⍝ divide every element by 1000
                         ⊢+                ⍝ add a back

{3⍕⍵/⍨1E¯6>|⎕-1○○⍵÷180}                  ⍝ filter the solutions
                  ○⍵÷180                   ⍝ convert to radian - π * ⍵ / 180
                1○                          ⍝ compute sine
             |⎕-                           ⍝ distance from x
       1E¯6>                                ⍝ small enough
    ⍵/⍨                                    ⍝ compress with the original list
 3⍕                                        ⍝ format to 3 decimal places
```

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 60 bytes

```
NumberForm[t/.NSolve[Sin[t/180Pi]==#&&#2<=t<=#3,{t}],{9,3}]&
```

input

> [0, -1080, 1080]

output

> {-1080.000,-900.000,-720.000,-540.000,-360.000,-180.000,0.000,180.000,360.000,540.000,720.000,900.000,1080.000}

Comment: Note that this solution doesn't work for large integers, for two reasons: the `9` limits the accuracy for large solutions, and also `NumberForm` displays the answer in scientific notation which erodes the accuracy (a constant annoyance from Mathematica). That being said, do you need `,Reals` at all? You can also save a byte by replacing `t Degree` with `t/180Pi`, which (despite appearances) evaluates to `πt/180`.

Answer (score 3):

## Fortran 95 (gfortran), 180 bytes

```
#define G >=i)write(*,'(f9.3)')
#define H read(*,*)
program a
H x
H i
H j
o=ASIN(x)*57.2957
p=o-180+o
q=o-360*999
do
r=q-p
if(r<=j.and.r G r
if(q>=j)exit
if(q G q
q=q+360
enddo
end
```

Structure ungolfed:

```
program a
        implicit none
        real :: x
        integer :: i
        integer :: j
        real :: o
        real :: r
        real :: q
        real :: p

        read(*,*) x
        read(*,*) i
        read(*,*) j

        o=ASIN(x)*57.2957
        p=o-180+o
        q=o-360*999

        do
                r=q-p
                if(r<=j.and.r >=i) then
                        write(*,'(f9.3)') r
                endif
                if(q>=j) then
                        exit
                endif
                if(q >=i) then
                        write(*,'(f9.3)') q
                endif
                q = q + 360
        end do
end program a
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 88 Bytes

```php
for([,$s,$f,$t]=$argv;$f<=$t;$f+=.001)round(sin(deg2rad($f)),5)!=$s?:printf("%.3f_",$f);
```

[Online Version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/181dbe0f689ec98b8826a984742482518da08990)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 100 bytes

```python
from math import*
x,a,b=input()
while a<=b:
    if round(sin(pi*a/180),5)==x:print a
    a=round(a+.001,3)
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#LY1RCoMwEES/zSkWvxIb7aZWEdscJraKCzWGGKm3t7EtDDM8GGYWnabpPvh5gsmEEWhysw8Z26SRnSbr1sAFe4/06sHcddeyhAbw82qffCHLHWXmrBoUshJab63zZAMYlhj9K5lTgahkKfZ49B9Sbb/1D76I27e@Y1EhSogqa2Q5FpcDq1rC5VoyjAMRc4VNjMM/)

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, <s>266</s>  <s>215</s> 210 bytes

```
g(y,a,b)==(r:List Float:=[];t:=y+truncate((a-y)/360)*360;repeat(t>b=>break;if t>=a then r:=append(r,[t]);t:=t+360);r)
f(x,a,b)==(abs(x)>1 or a>b=>[];y:=asin(x)*180/%pi;z:=180-y;sort(append(g(y,a,b),g(z,a,b))))
```

ungolf and test

```
-- g/180=r/pi  => r=pi*g/180
--y+k*360=a
--    a-y
-- k=------
--    360
-- find all angles of the same class of angles [y+k*360] in interval [a,b]
gg(y,a,b)==
   r:List Float:=[]
   t:=y+truncate((a-y)/360)*360 --truncate(1.9)=1, truncate(-3.1)=-4 is ok
   repeat
     t>b=>break
     if t>=a then r:=append(r,[t])
     t:=t+360
   r

-- ff returns the list of solution y of sin(y)=x with y in the interval [a,b]
ff(x,a,b)==
   abs(x)>1 or a>b =>[]
   y:=asin(x)*180/%pi -- z and y are the only 2 solutions in one 360 Len interval 
   z:=180-y
   sort(append(gg(y,a,b),gg(z,a,b)))


(6) -> f(0.5, 0, 360)
   (6)  [30.0,150.0]
                                                         Type: List Float
(7) -> f(-0.2, 56, 243)
   (7)  [191.5369590328 1548769]
                                                         Type: List Float
(8) -> f(0.0, -1080, 1080)
   (8)
   [- 1080.0, - 900.0, - 720.0, - 540.0, - 360.0, - 180.0, 0.0, 180.0, 360.0,
    540.0, 720.0, 900.0, 1080.0]

(14) -> m:=f(-0.1, -2035, -243)
   (14)
   [- 1974.2608295227 33214, - 1805.7391704772 66786, - 1614.2608295227 33214,
    - 1445.7391704772 66786, - 1254.2608295227 33214, - 1085.7391704772 66786,
    - 894.2608295227 332137, - 725.7391704772 667863, - 534.2608295227 332137,
    - 365.7391704772 667863]
                                                         Type: List Float
(15) -> map(x+->sin(%pi*x/180), m)
   (15)
   [- 0.0999999999 9999999987, - 0.1000000000 0000000016,
    - 0.0999999999 9999999986 2, - 0.1000000000 0000000028,
    - 0.0999999999 9999999985 4, - 0.1000000000 0000000018,
    - 0.0999999999 999999999, - 0.1000000000 0000000019,
    - 0.0999999999 9999999989 2, - 0.1000000000 0000000014]
                                                         Type: List Float
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 74 bytes

```r
function(x,a,b,u=seq(a,b,.001))sprintf("%.3f",u[abs(sinpi(u/180)-x)<1e-6])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzBCoMwEETv/QoRhF3YpBtTg4f6JdKDFhdySdUY8O/TBIaZxzvMmWXKksL38r8ANy20UpridkAlzWwQ4376cAm0nbbSUpqXNUL0YfeQnmZkVDe@zabcB7MA64GZmhLrGB8CinVfzeCo6V@2Ki7HxSjDY5namP8)

The tolerance `1e-6` was chosen to fit the second test case, so is somewhat arbitrary. This answer takes advantage of R's vectorized functions.